# Get lowercase with keydown wpf

Tags: wpf

I want to get the keys pressed on the keyboard either with or without caplock:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
   e.Key.ToString();
}
```

When I type "a" or "A" on the keyboard, the result of e.Key is always "A". How can I get 'a' for entering 'a'?

Answer (score 8):

You can't use the `KeyDown` event. You'll need to use the `TextInput` event. This will print the original letter with it's caption (Uppercase/Lowercase).

```
    private void Window_TextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Text);
    }
```

Now, this will also print the Shift and so on if it's pressed. If you don't want those modifiers just get the last item of the string -treat it as a char array ;)-

Comment: strange, textinput does not get fired?

Comment: @olidev Check the object tree to see if you're attaching it the proper UIElement. Start attaching the event to the Window and then go down.

Comment: but textInput will get fired also from the code, I want to get event handler only from the key input

Answer (score 7):

You can check in your `KeyDown` event whether `CAPS lock` is on or off using [Control.IsKeyLocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.iskeylocked%28VS.80%29.aspx) method. Also, you might need to check if user typed in capital using `Shift` key which can be identified using `Modifiers` enum like this -

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   string key = e.Key.ToString();
   bool isCapsLockOn = System.Windows.Forms.Control
                        .IsKeyLocked(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.CapsLock);
   bool isShiftKeyPressed = (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift)
                                == ModifierKeys.Shift;
   if (!isCapsLockOn && !isShiftKeyPressed)
   {
      key = key.ToLower();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Overriding TextInput/PreviewTextInput (or listening to the events) should work.

```
protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);
    Console.WriteLine(e.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[KeyEventArgs class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.aspx) has "Shift" field which indicating whether the SHIFT key was pressed.

Otherwise, because Window_KeyDown method will be called when CAPS_LOCK pressed, you can save a 
bool value indicating whether the CAPS_LOCK key was pressed.

```
    bool isCapsLockPressed;
    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e) {
           if(e.KeyCode == Keys.CapsLock) {
               isCapsLockPressed = !isCapsLockPressed;
           }
    }
```

Comment: What if CapsLock is on when the app is started?  Wouldn't that throw everything off?

Comment: Or even if caps lock gets pressed when the application isn't in focus.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is by using Window_TextInput event rather than KeyDown.

But as you said this event does not fire on your application you can rather use a hack like this :

```
bool iscapsLock = false;
bool isShift = false;
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.CapsLock)
        iscapsLock = !iscapsLock;

    if (e.Key >= Key.A && e.Key <= Key.Z)
    {
        bool shift = isShift;
        if (iscapsLock)
            shift = !shift;
        int s = e.Key.ToString()[0];
        if (!shift)
        {
            s += 32;
        }
        Debug.Write((char)s);
    }

}
```

This will properly print the characters based on whether capslock is turned on or not. The initial value of the Capslock can be retrieved using this link :

http://cboard.cprogramming.com/csharp-programming/105103-how-detect-capslock-csharp.html

I hope this works for you.