# e.KeyCode returns 'A' instead of 'a'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, textbox, listbox, keydown

In `listBox_KeyDown`, I evaluate the `e.KeyCode` condition. But it detects Upper-case characters instead of the lower-case (which is actually typed). How do I get it to capture the actual character typed? Code follows:

```
bool isLetterOrDigit = char.IsLetterOrDigit((char)e.KeyCode);
if (isLetterOrDigit == true)
{
    //Add the char to textBox
    txtINAME.Text += (char)e.KeyCode;
}
```

Comment: Or, if this is about WPF (hard to tell) [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591793/get-lowercase-with-keydown-wpf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `KeyPress` event, it has a `KeyChar` property in the `KeyPressEventArgs`. It will get you the actual character being pressed